# Unable to infer closure type in the current context (SwiftSignalRClient)

Tags: swift, signalr, closures

I have created a new project and am trying to implement the SwiftSignalR framework. In my last project, there were no problems with the following code. However, in the new project I am getting a closure type error and could really do with some help!

The actual error reads: **Unable to infer closure type in the current context**

I really can't understand why this error is appearing now and not in my previous project beyond the fact I switched from Swift 4.2 to Swift 5.0 and iOS deployment target from 12.0 to 13.0

My code is as follows:

```
private var connection: HubConnection

connection.on(method: "LocationBroadcast") { locationUpdate, _ in
        self.locationUpdateReceived(locationUpdate as! [Dictionary<String, Any>])
    }

private func locationUpdateReceived(_ locationUpdate: [Dictionary<String, Any>]) {
    print("Location update recieved")
}
```

Comment: what framework do you use for SignalR?

Comment: I use the SwiftSignalR framework - https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftSignalRClient

Answer (score 3):

The issue seem to be caused by changes in the SignalR-Client-Swift API, the earlier one expected two parameters of types [Any?] and TypeConverter, now it has ArgumentExtractor and a bunch of generic overloads. In general your new code will look something like this

```
private var connection: HubConnection

connection.on(method: "LocationBroadcast") { extractor in
    let locationUpdate = try extractor.getArgument(type: [Dictionary<String, Any>].self)
    self.locationUpdateReceived(locationUpdate)
}

private func locationUpdateReceived(_ locationUpdate: [Dictionary<String, Any>]) {
    print("Location update recieved")
}
```

However, this wouldn't compile yet, because new api requires Decodable type so you can't use Any here and to change it some other type, so the code should look like this:

```
struct LocationInfo: Codable {
    var value: String
}

private var connection: HubConnection

connection.on(method: "LocationBroadcast") { extractor in
    let locationUpdate = try extractor.getArgument(type: [Dictionary<String, LocationInfo>].self)
    self.locationUpdateReceived(locationUpdate)
}

private func locationUpdateReceived(_ locationUpdate: [Dictionary<String, LocationInfo>]) {
    print("Location update recieved")
}
```

Comment: Thank for taking the time to look at this. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately private func locationUpdateReceived never receives a location update.

Comment: @Chris is there an exception on getArgument? Can you provide an updated code that causes the issue?

Comment: No, there is no exception but when a SignalR message comes through it never calls the locationUpdateReceived function. 
The good news is there are no errors and the code builds perfectly okay. Now I just need to ensure that when a message comes through, I can extract the dictionary data and do something with it. It's as though the getArgument fails but there is no exception.

Comment: @Chris that doesn't seem likely, as soon as execution reaches getArgument, the locationUpdateReceived wouldn't be called if there is either exception or crash. Did you try catching exception there?

Answer (score 1):

For Swift Codable I am using this.

```
private var connection: HubConnection

connection.on(method: "LocationBroadcast", callback: { (jsonResponse: JSON) in
            print(jsonResponse)

            do {
                let locationBroadcast:LocationBroadcast = try JSONDecoder().decode(LocationBroadcast.self, from: jsonResponse.rawData())
            }catch(let error) {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })

struct LocationBroadcast: Codable {
    var value: String
}
```

Comment: This helped solve my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make pod version to

pod 'SwiftSignalRClient', '~> 0.5.0'

This has resolved the issue without changing the code for me.